# How to put the time and date on a logout PHP script

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there's a way of putting the date and time on a PHP script so that when a user logs out, it displays something along the lines of `You logged out on the 19/04/2016 at 11:00AM`. The `PHP` script that I have is

```
<?php

// include function files for this application
require_once('bookmark_fns.php');
session_start();
$old_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];

// store  to test if they *were* logged in
unset($_SESSION['valid_user']);
$result_dest = session_destroy();

// start output html
do_html_header('Logging Out');

if (!empty($old_user)) {
  if ($result_dest)  {
    // if they were logged in and are now logged out
    echo 'Logged out.<br />';
    do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
  } else {
    // they were logged in and could not be logged out
    echo 'Could not log you out.<br />';
  }
} else {
  // if they weren't logged in but came to this page somehow
  echo 'You were not logged in, and so have not been logged out.<br />';
  do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
}

do_html_footer();

?>
```

Comment: fire a query to insert the date and time just before `session_destroy`

Comment: write datetime to database or file when user logout.

Comment: Just echo the message along the datetime `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` if you're not planning to save this information into your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [date](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) function it's easy :

```
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$time = date("H:iA");
echo "You logged out on the $date at $time";
// return You logged out on the 19/04/2016 at 02:59AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one simple line, you didn't specify that you wanted to insert this into the database, if you did, you'd need to use an insert statement in the same place of the echo statement, using the same technique to grab the current time.

```
if (!empty($old_user)) {
    if ($result_dest)  {
    // if they were logged in and are now logged out
    echo 'Logged out.<br />';
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Displays message, of the current datetime.
    echo "You logged out at: $date";

    do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
} else {
    // they were logged in and could not be logged out
    echo 'Could not log you out.<br />';
}
```

[These](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp) examples I think you will find helpful.